# fileinput upload and preview, protect files

Tags: php, jquery, security

What I am trying to find out is how to protect those files from unrestricted access. I can understand that if these files are not in the public folder then the JQuery plugin won't be able to load them, but then everyone could guess the link in the end, and for example user one could just type the link and download some other user's images, is there any way to protect it?

**JQuery:**

```
function files(sort) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxScripts/getFile.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {sort: sort},
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var preview = [];
                var test = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    preview.push(item.RelativePath);
                    console.log(item);
                    test.push({type: item.Type, caption: item.Title + ' ' + item.ExamDate, key: item.UserExamsID, url: 'ajaxScripts/deleteFile.php', downloadUrl: item.RelativePath});
                });
                $("#file-input").fileinput({
                    theme: 'fa',
                    uploadUrl: 'ajaxScripts/upload.php',
                    maxFileSize: 10000,
                    overwriteInitial: false,
                    initialPreview: preview,
                    initialPreviewAsData: true,
                    initialPreviewConfig: test,
                    purifyHtml: true

                });

            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("XMLHttpRequest=" + XMLHttpRequest + "; textStatus=" + textStatus + "; errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

**PHP:**
getFile.php

```
require_once 'DBconfig.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    header("Location: /index.html");
    die();
}
$sort = $_POST['sort'];
$userID = $_SESSION['user_session'];


try {
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT `RelativePath`,`Title`,`ExamDate`, `UserExamsID`, `Type` FROM `userexams` WHERE `UserID`=:userid AND UserExamsID>21 ORDER BY `ExamDate` ASC");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($res);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**and upload.php**
I won't post the code, but it basically, creates a folder with the userid as name in the web root folder so /uploads/{userid} and stores the files with their original name + a random string in the end to avoid same name file conflicts, then writes the path to the database, as well as it's original filename and the user id it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the uploaded files outside of the webroot and use PHP to return them after checking the user has access.  For example:

```
// Let the browser know to expect a binary file
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    // Block access for users not logged in
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    die();
}
$userID = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$path = $_GET['path'];
// Check the logged in user is requesting one of their own files
// (Probably want something more elaborate; this is just an example)
if (strpos($path, '/uploads/' . $userID . '/') === false) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    die();
}

// Security check the request is valid (again, just one example)
if (strpos($path, '..') !== false) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    die();
}

// Return the image
readfile('/path/to/uploads' . $path);
```

Wherever you want to request the image from the client side call this script with the path as a parameter.  If you'd like to display the images inline you'll need to determine the correct MIME type and set it in the Content-Type header.